# Перед загрузкой страницы мигает белый фон

Tags: css

Пробовала сжать изображение, это не помогает. Подскажите новичку, что делать.

```
body { 
background: url(../img/background-min.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Решается, как и описали выше, заменой фона на тот, который в преимуществе у вашей фоновой картинки.

А также, сжатие лучше сделать либо специальными алгоритмами, которые сжимают готофрафию без потерии качества, либо сервисами, которые работают с подобными алгоритмами. **Как пример [kraken.io](https://kraken.io/?ref=8a4d55f2966c)**

Answer (score 0):

Изображение просто не успевает загрузиться. Можете выставить цвет фона, например синий, чтобы не так сильно заметно было.

```
body{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Или сделать прелоадер

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
#preloader{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Здесь должен быть стиль прелоадора
        ВНИМАНИЕ! Отдельно от основного стиля !-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="preloader"><p>Загрузка...</p></div>
    <!-- После прелоадора идёт всё содержимое сайта
         И в самом конце подключаются стили и скрипты
         Так же js код для закрытия прелоадера-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Так как веб страница загружается и обрабатывается последовательно сверху вниз, прелоадер помещённый на самый верх будет загружен первым и закроет собой загружающееся содержимое. После полной загрузки страницы он будет закрыт js кодом в самом низу страницы.

Надеюсь, помог.

Comment: Это не помогает, в результате - синий экран вместо белого, выглядит не менее раздражающе

Comment: @АлинаСавчук я лишь привёл пример, цвет ставьте какой вам угодно

Comment: А можно сделать плавное появление background-image? Или оно так не работает?

Comment: @моргание происходит потому, что картинка не успевает полностью загрузиться. Я могу расписать плавное появление после полной загрузки страницы или блока, ибо чтобы фон появлялся нужен уже загруженный фон